# Extending a JOOQ Table class

Tags: jooq

I have a 'document' table (very original) that I need to dynamically subset at runtime so that my API consumers can't see data that isn't legal to view given some temporal constraints between the application/database. JOOQ created me a nice auto-gen Document class that represents this table.

Ideally, I'd like to create an anonymous subclass of Document that actually translates to

```
SELECT document.* FROM document, other_table 
WHERE document.id = other_table.doc_id AND other_table.foo = 'bar'
```

Note that bar is dynamic at runtime hence the desire to extend it anonymously. I can extend the Document class anonymously and everything looks great to my API consumers, but I can't figure out how to actually restrict the data. accept() is final and toSQL doesn't seem to have any effect.

If this isn't possible and I need to extend CustomTable, what method do I override to provide my custom SQL? The JOOQ docs say to override accept(), but that method is marked final in TableImpl, which CustomTable extends from. This is on JOOQ 3.5.3.

Thanks,
Kyle

### UPDATE

I built 3.5.4 from source after removing the "final" modifier on TableImpl.accept() and was able to do exactly what I wanted. Given that the docs imply I should be able to override accept perhaps it's just a simple matter of an erroneous final declaration.

Comment: I don't know, but JOOQ is against extension http://blog.jooq.org/tag/final-keyword/

Comment: The autogenerated extensions of Table are not marked final so that gave me hope...

Comment: @xenoterracide: That's not entirely correct. jOOQ just prefers well-designed extension points over random, unforeseen extensions... Though, I do feel that this will evolve in an off-topic discussion, here :)

Comment: @LukasEder - is it a mistake that accept() is marked final in TableImpl?

Comment: @kylejmcintyre: No, but it's probably a mistake that `CustomTable` extends `TableImpl`...

Comment: Okay. I must say the custom build I did where accept could be overridden allowed for a really convenient extension of a generated table... :)

Comment: @kylejmcintyre: I can see the application, but are you sure you've gotten everything right? What happens when you alias that table? When you reference columns of such an alias? Etc... Sooner or later you'll work against the design, which is why the method was final :). But again, I can see the application. Anyway, why don't you provide a full answer to your question, with code? This would be very useful for future visitors of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can implement one of the interfaces

- TableLike (and delegate all methods to a JOOQ implementation instance) such as TableImpl (dynamic field using a HashMap to store the Fields?)
- Implement the Field interface (and make it dynamic)

Anyway you will need to remind that there are different phases while JOOQ builds the query, binds values, executes it etc. You should probably avoid changing the "foo" Field when starting to build a query.

It's been a while since I worked with JOOQ. My team ended up building a customized JOOQ. Another (dirty) trick to hook into the JOOQ library was to use the same packages, as the protected identifier makes everything visible within the same package as well as to sub classes...